# Is it possible that a free relative clause overlaps a clause applying to extraposition?

Tags: sentence-construction, extraposition

Here are two sentences with similar construction.

> 1. (What they are proposing to do) is (horrifying).

Extraposition: It is horrifying what they are proposing to do.

> 2. (What she said) is (true）.
>    It is true what she said. (?? It seems impossible. Why?)

Supposing they are in the same condition of SVC constructure, can the second sentence, the free relative clause, be extraposed to the end of the sentence?
As we know, in the first sentence extraposition is preferred.

If we rephrase both the wh-clauses (or noun phrases) into these, both 1a and 2a are fine.

1a. That (or The thing) which they are proposing to do is horrifying.

2a  That (or The thing) which she said is true.

Comment: "As we know, in the first sentence extraposition is preferred." I *don't* know that this is true, frankly. I would probably be more likely to use your first example when speaking normally.

Comment: It's not clear what you're getting at with the last two examples. For starters, the word order is "that which", not "which that". What is the question you are asking about these two?

Comment: Sorry for typing mistakes.  I am a little sleepy.

Comment: I listed as much information as possible to interpret the similarity between the two examples. My question is whether or not example #2 can apply to extraposition?

Comment: In colloquial American English, **It's true, what she said** is possible. It tends to have an exclamatory or emphatic tone. "It's unreasonable, what you're asking me to do!"

Comment: What @Tim said. *It is true what she said* looks "peculiar" written out like that, but *It's true. What she said* is an utterly unexceptional utterance. And we don't always speak in sentences, so who cares how I punctuated it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Yes

"It is true what she said" is grammatical. You are already familiar with the term for this construction: extraposition.

"It's true what they say" is a common phrase in English, often immediately followed by an [idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom) (the thing "they" say that is true).